# Python asyncio: Cancel streams server and all clients

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a streams server that handles multiple independent clients. When I shut it down I want to notify all clients that the server has shut down.

I figured out how to close the server to new connections, but not how to cancel the specific handlers waiting for client data.

So far the only solution I found is to cancel all tasks in the loop, but this doesn't work for me as I have other tasks that must finish their jobs first.

Does asyncio provide some interface for this or do I have to keep track of all connections myself and cancel them once the server shuts down? I would prefer if the connection handler catches an exception when it calls `await reader.readuntil()` and not in the middle of execution, but this is not required.

Right now the client looses connection without warning. With this it cannot tell if it was a network issue or if the server shut down.

```py
import asyncio
import signal

server = None
shutdown = False

async def important_task():
    while not shutdown:
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        print("I am important")

async def handle_conn(reader,writer):
    print("Got connection")
    try:
        while True:
            text = await reader.readuntil(b'\n')
            # Do stuff
            writer.write( text ) # Echo example
            await writer.drain()
    except serverShutdownException: # How do I cause something like this?
        writer.write(b"Goodbye")
        await writer.drain()
    finally:
        writer.close()
        await writer.wait_closed()

def handle_sig(num,frame):
    global shutdown
    print(f"Caught {num}")
    server.close()
    shutdown = True

async def serve():
    global server
    server = await asyncio.start_server(handle_conn,"127.0.0.1",8080)
    try:
        await server.serve_forever()
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        pass
    await server.wait_closed()
    # wait for all handlers to be done?

def main():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_sig)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    t1 = loop.create_task(serve())
    t2 = loop.create_task(important_task())
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(t1,t2))

main()
```